# Stretches to make my wrist more flexible

Tags: stretching, flexibility, wrist

I recently punched someone, and now my right wrist is not as flexible as the left one. I can bend it to around 45 degrees but then it becomes painful, so I have to stop. I need to make it more flexible so I can start doing push-ups again. Do you have any good ideas for stretches?

Comment: Any sign of swelling? It might have been sprained.

Comment: ^what he said. Did you go see a doctor about this?

Comment: I once broke a bone in my hand, I did'nt know it had been broken until an (unrelated) X-ray years later. Take home lesson: Make sure you know what's wrong with your hand before trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If the pain is that bad, I do highly recommend a doctor, as badly healed injuries in something as mobile as a wrist can be bad news. As regards stretching, I advise looking at [Aikido wrist stretches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA0Urm6WVCU). They cover a fairly wide range of movement and are easy to adjust to your current flexibility.

On a side note, I had something like this happen to me a few years back. I let my wrist relax too much while hitting the punching bag. I made a full recovery and it turned out to be nothing worse than a sprain. I wore a wrist guard for a while, and found that pushups were much less painful when I did them on my fists, as it involves a straight wrist.

Answer (score 1):

You have to visit a doctor to get a thorough diagnosis.

You could have two types of injuries as you punched.

1. The direct bone to bone punch could have got you a hairline fracture, (checkout the boxers fracture aswell)
2. Or it could be a sprain. This is more likely, but be careful, stretching a sprained ligament only aggravates the problem, if it is a minor sprain, then you have to wear wrist support till the sprain heals itself.

Answer (score 1):

It worth for doc to take a look at it. But if you want to stretch it then take a pencil in your hand and bend it till one side till the point it gets uncomfortable, NOT PAINFUL, keep it in this position for 20-30 seconds. Then the same to the other side. Keep doing it left, right, up, down and diagonals as much as you can.

This is what my doctor told me to do to recover after a surgery on my wrist. You can do this exercise anywhere(home, public transport, lecture, during a meal) it does not take your attention and helps to get back the flexibility fairly quick if you do not forget to do this

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrist support band that you can purchase. It helps stabilize the wrist which in essence enables you to do strength training. Although not a cure, this will help tremendously. Healing may take some time as we use and flex our wrists daily.